# How do I stop my countdown timer from executing after it has reached the deadline on refresh of my browser

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

This is how the JavaScript looks like. I tried searching for solutions but couldn't find. Please I need detailed solutions. Online I kept seeing cookies but I don't know how to use it in this case.

```
  function countDown() {
      var now = new Date();
      var eventDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

      var currentTime = now.getTime();
      var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

      var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

      var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
      var m = Math.floor(s/60);
      var h = Math.floor(m/60);
      var d = Math.floor(h/24);

      h %= 24;
      m %= 60;
      s %= 60;

      h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h: h;
      m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m: m;
      s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s: s;

      document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
      document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

      document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
      document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
      document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

      var t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);

      if (d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {
        clearTimeout(t);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
      }
  }
  countDown();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is unclear, without a clear and well thought out question you're unlikely to get a clear and well thought out answer. What is your expected behaviour, and what's your code doing instead? Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Comment: It's a countdown timer that executes past the eventTime. I want it to stop executing when eventTime is equal to currentTime. But anytime I refresh the browser the cleartimeOut stops and the timer continues counting.

Comment: The countdown is built using HTML table tag

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with your code is in the date checking logic.

Checking with `==` will only give you a truthy response if the datetime (or part thereof) is the same as the value you're checking it against.

However, you need to check whether the date is already past. To do this, you need to use a `<` or `<=` operator.

Here's an example of what I mean. The info is `console.log`ed instead, you can re-implement the DOM editing you have in your question.

```js
  function countDown() {
      var now = new Date();
      var eventDate = new Date(2020, 4, 22); // 22 May 2020

      var currentTime = now.getTime();
      var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

      var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

      var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
      var m = Math.floor(s/60);
      var h = Math.floor(m/60);
      var d = Math.floor(h/24);

      h %= 24;
      m %= 60;
      s %= 60;

      h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h: h;
      m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m: m;
      s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s: s;

      var t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);

      // This if statement only runs exactly on eventDate
      if (d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
      }
      
      // This if statement will run if we're past or exactly on eventDate
      if (remTime <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(t);
      }
      
      // This console.log shows that the numbers become negative after the date
      console.log(remTime, d,h,m,s);
  }
  countDown();
```